# Email notification on a selected tag

Tags: support

I'd like to receive email notification about new post with selected set of tags. Is it possible?

Answer (score 9):

You can go to https://stackexchange.com/filters and create a filter for your selected set of tags and set instructions about email notifications:

[image]

Maybe an alternative which is easier to manage and customise: using a newsfeed instead of email. For every {tag} you'll find the link at the bottom of the page:

[image]